# Water that came outta urethra after istinja in woman

Tags: salat, taharah

I already asked this question on a website & got this answer, just want to confirm if it's right or not. Assalamu Alaikum sister. As for your question, if some water comes out of the urethra after performing istinja, it does not your wudu. You can consider your wudu to be valid and continue with your prayers.